# Convert dataframe to lists

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a problem in converting a dataframe into lists. I grouped the dataframe to count how many unique values occurring in the dataframe and the code that I used and the output are as follows.

```
result = result.groupby('pudo_coords').agg(points=('pudo_coords', 'size'))

                                    points
                      pudo_coords
-6.14701651808333,106.830329925      10
-6.14861928847368,106.837115521053   17
-6.15660049156522,106.855077395652   14
-6.15682032492857,106.846344864286   12
-6.15857122352381,106.836970171429   20
```

Now I trying to convert the output into lists using this code, however the output only displays the points instead of the pudo_coords, points.

```
result = result.values.tolist()

[[10],
 [17],
 [14],
 [12],
 [20],
 [12]]
```

My intended result is as follows :

```
[['-6.14701651808333,106.830329925',['-6.14861928847368,106.837115521053','-6.15660049156522,106.855077395652','-6.15682032492857,106.846344864286','-6.15857122352381,106.836970171429'], [10, 17, 14, 12, 20]]
```

Can someone help me with this?
 Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

your `groupby` has not the `as_index` param, so your index are the coordinates.

So first fix your goupby with this:

```
result = result.groupby('pudo_coords', as_index = False).agg(points=('pudo_coords', 'size'))
```

Then get the values by column:

```
coordinates = result['pudo_coords'].values.tolist()
points = result['points'].values.tolist()
```

Finally, put all in one list:

```
final_data = [coordinates, points]

print(final_data)
Output: [['-6.14701651808333,106.830329925',['-6.14861928847368,106.837115521053','-6.15660049156522,106.855077395652','-6.15682032492857,106.846344864286','-6.15857122352381,106.836970171429'], [10, 17, 14, 12, 20]]
```